# Google Cloud App Engine, .Net core WebAPI

Tags: c#, angular, google-app-engine, asp.net-core-3.1

I have deployed an Angular app on .Net core 3.1 backend with a web API to Google cloud app engine.
It's all looks good including the connection to my mongodb cluster, and the Angular app is up and running **but it looks like my API endpoints are not responding to the app**. I'm not getting any errors though... just an Internal error 500 detailed below.

I ran this app locally while connected to the mongo cluster and it works just fine so the connection there is good.

Do I need to do something extra to make this API work?
This is my Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      var ClientDomain = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientDomain");
      services.AddCors(cfg => cfg.AddPolicy("ClientDomain", builder => builder.WithOrigins(ClientDomain)
      .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()));

      services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
      {
        o.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
        o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
      });
      services.AddControllers();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.Use(async (context, next) =>
      {
      await next();
      if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
      {
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
          await next();
        }
      });


      app.UseHttpsRedirection();

      app.UseRouting();
      app.UseDefaultFiles();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
      {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Resources")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/Resources")
      });
      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
      });
    }
```

edit: Found this error:
System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/localhost:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.

Comment: Check the logs on the server. Should be the first place you look for 500 errors.

Comment: @R.Richards there are no relevant logs there...

Comment: Have you tried calling the api endpoints directly to see if any useful error information is returned?
Or adding logging e.g.NLog to the api to get details of any errors?

Comment: added the error from the server. sorry for the misleading info <3

Comment: Is your cluster inside the GCP architecture, or are you trying to reach it from somewhere else? I ask this due to thie fact that this may be an issue with the firewall rules in the project